# SQL Server : can't select columns of one table by filtering from another table on same database issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using this statement to fetch the rows from one table by filtering the data from another table.

```
 SELECT EMPNO 
 FROM EMP 
 WHERE CITY_NAME = 'Los Angeles';
```

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
>   Invalid column name 'CITY_NAME'.

Actually I need to fetch EMPNO FROM EMP by filtering all people from 'Los Angeles'

I also try this statement but it doesn't work either:

```
SELECT EMPNO 
FROM EMP 
WHERE dbo.LOCATION.CITY_NAME = 'Los Angeles';
```

[image: IMAGE OF ALL TABLE]

*NOTE*: these are all on the same server and same database

Thank you.

Comment: can you tell me which columns are primary key?and connection between tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need JOIN between the tables.

```
 SELECT EMPNO FROM EMP 
 JOIN DEPT ON EMP.DeptNo = DEPT.DeptNo
 JOIN LOCATION ON LOCATION.City_ID = DEPT.City_ID 
 WHERE LOCATION.CITY_NAME='Los Angeles';
```

Comment: Just to point out that table names are  DEPT, EMP and LOCATION (see mssms tree)

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 tables:

1. EMP
2. LOCATION
3. DEPT

Query will be

```
SELECT 
    EMP.* 
FROM 
    EMP 
JOIN 
    DEPT ON EMO.DEPTNO = DEPT.DEPTNO
JOIN
    LOCATION ON LOCATION.CITY_ID = DEPT.CITY_ID
WHERE 
    LOCATION.CITY_NAME = 'Los Angeles'
```

This can be achiveved by join.

Answer (score 0):

you do not habe a column named city_name in emp table but city_id 
so  you have a table named location with city_id and city_name as column

you only habe to join the both table using city_id and you will be able to filter by the column city_name.

`SELECT EMPNO 
 FROM EMP e, DEPT d, LOCATION l 
WHERE e.CITY_ID = l.CITY_ID
  AND e.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO
  AND l.CITY_NAME = 'Los Angeles';`